# Custom window moving code. How to deal with rapid mouse movements?

Tags: wpf, window, mouseevent

I've created my own code for moving windows around, using the following system:

- mousedown (in a certain area) activates the move
- track mousemove events to move window with cursor
- mouseup event completes the move

This works great except in cases where the mouse is moved so fast that the cursor leaves my window, before firing a mousemove event, thus not giving me a chance to move the window in the direction the cursor is moving.

Any solutions to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you are after is `Mouse.Capture`.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437639/how-do-i-use-capturemouse-or-mouse-capture-in-my-c-sharp-wpf-application) has some more details on use within WPF.

Comment: Cool. Had no idea this existed. Thank you sir.